# How to embed php website url with id by javascript or div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to embed a single page php website(form) to another site. when I embed the site, the embedded code should have a unique id value through URL for identification. It is used for many embedded codes with different unique ids. So is it possible to do it in `<object>` or javascript?. Please help me code it.

Comment: If you continue ask and wait for someone code it for you. You never receive any answer. Please try code by yourself. If have errors we will help you fix it.

Comment: Everything is possible, You have make your first step to create the project now start trying some code on it, If you face some problems with your CODE we will be happy to help out :)

Comment: thank you guys i fixed the problems . is there any source link for ajax to study to improve my coding, thanks

Comment: @Guru type "ajax tutorial" into google.